# I want to deploy more django websites on single server. Is apache with virtualhosts my only option?

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, gunicorn

I want to have multiple django websites on a single server.
I have done this with php and apache's virtualhosts.

But how do I do this with django?

Can I make use of gunicorn or other python wsgi solutions, or do I have to use apache?

What are the pros and cons of apache and other solutions in this case?

What are caveats?

Answer (score 1):

To do this with apache you can use multiple `virtualhosts` just like in php
I asked a question on how to do this on serverfault found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/357804/apache2-mod-wsgi-django-named-virtual-servers)

Comment: I understand, but can I do it with gunicorn & nginx?